# Remove all elements of sublist except the last

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, list, linq-to-entities

Hi everyone I have a list of type "Sign" (EF entity) which has another list of SignDataObject (another EF entity). I need to retrieve all signs from the db containing only the last SignDataObject (based on the timestamp (which is a date time).

Right now I wanted to take things in steps and did this to retrieve all my signs (with all the signdataobjects in it):

```
var signs = context.Signs
                .Include("SignDataObjects")
                .Where(s => s.Customer.Email.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower()))
                .ToList();
```

Then I wanted to iterate through each sign's signdataobject and remove all the children's except the last.

I tried to do this but didn't work:

```
foreach (var sign in signs){
                sign.SignDataObjects.ToList().RemoveRange(0, Math.Max(0, sign.SignDataObjects.Count-1));
            }
```

Then I tried to do it in more steps like so:

```
foreach (var sign in signs)
            {
                //sign.SignDataObjects.ToList().RemoveRange(0, Math.Max(0, sign.SignDataObjects.Count-1));
                var sdol = sign.SignDataObjects.ToList();

                sdol.RemoveRange(0, Math.Max(0, sdol.Count - 1));
                sign.SignDataObjects = sdol;
            }
```

and it works.

I wasn't able to delete the sublist children while iterating over it so I am asking, is there a faster / better method of doing this? Maybe in the very start when I retrieve my signs, I may be able to retrieve them already including only the last signobjectdata directly rather than iterating through it later?

Sign Entity:

```
public Sign()
    {
        this.SignDataObjects = new HashSet<SignDataObject>();
    }

    public string SensorID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string RefSignType { get; set; }
    public int RefCustomerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual SignType SignType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SignDataObject> SignDataObjects { get; set; }
```

SignDataObject:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Orientation { get; set; }
    public int SensorBattery { get; set; }
    public string RefSignID { get; set; }

    public virtual Sign Sign { internal get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the type of `SignDataObjects`

Comment: It's its own type, it is a EF entity.

Comment: So your question is retrieving Signs that include last SignDataObjects only?

Comment: So, basically every sign has a certain number of SignDataObjects. I want to retrieve all signs (for a certain customer) and they should include ONLY the last SignDataObject.

Comment: What property that is used to determine that it's the last SignDataObject? Timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it works, I used `TimeStamp` property to determine that it is the last `SignDataObject` in the collection.

```
var signs = context.Signs
    .Include(s => s.SignDataObjects)
    .Where(s => s.Customer.Email.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower()))
    .Select(s => new 
     { 
        Sign = s, 
        SignDataObjects = s.SignDataObjects.OrderByDescending(sdo => sdo.Timestamp).Take(1) 
     })
    .ToArray()
    .Select(s => s.Sign)
    .ToArray();
```